# Check if a type implements an interface in Julia

Tags: julia

How to check that a type implements an interface in Julia?

For exemple iteration interface is implemented by the functions `start`, `next`, `done`.

I need is to have a specialization of a function depending on wether the argument type implements a given interface or not.

*EDIT*

Here is an example of what I would like to do.

Consider the following code:

```
a = [7,8,9]
f = 1.0    
s = Set()
push!(s,30)
push!(s,40)

function getsummary(obj)
  println("Object of type ", typeof(obj))
end

function getsummary{T<:AbstractArray}(obj::T)
  println("Iterable Object starting with ", next(obj, start(obj))[1])
end

getsummary(a)
getsummary(f)
getsummary(s)
```

The output is:

```
Iterable Object starting with 7
Object of type Float64
Object of type Set{Any}
```

Which is what we would expect since `Set` is not an `AbstractArray`. But clearly my second method only requires the type T to implement the iteration interface.

my issue isn't only related to the iteration interface but to all interfaces defined by a set of functions.

*EDIT-2*

I think my question is related to

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5

Since we could have imagined something like `T<:Iterable`

Comment: if i understand correctly, you are looking for `methodswith()`?

Comment: @GnimucK. Yes, something like that. but I don't see a clean way to implement dynamic dispatch using `methodswith()` : I would like to define two functions and depending on whether a type implements an interface or not the right function will be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, this is done with traits. See [Traits.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Traits.jl) for one implementation; a similar approach is used in `Base` to dispatch on `Base.iteratorsize`, `Base.linearindexing`, etc. For instance, this is how `Base` implements `collect` using the `iteratorsize` trait:

```
"""
    collect(element_type, collection)

Return an `Array` with the given element type of all items in a collection or iterable.
The result has the same shape and number of dimensions as `collection`.
"""
collect{T}(::Type{T}, itr) = _collect(T, itr, iteratorsize(itr))

_collect{T}(::Type{T}, itr, isz::HasLength) = copy!(Array{T,1}(Int(length(itr)::Integer)), itr)
_collect{T}(::Type{T}, itr, isz::HasShape)  = copy!(similar(Array{T}, indices(itr)), itr)
function _collect{T}(::Type{T}, itr, isz::SizeUnknown)
    a = Array{T,1}(0)
    for x in itr
        push!(a,x)
    end
    return a
end
```

See also [Mauro Werder's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9w8oHfG1Ic&feature=youtu.be) on traits.

I would define a `iterability(::T)` trait as follows:

```
immutable Iterable end
immutable NotIterable end
iterability(T) =
    if method_exists(length, (T,)) || !isa(Base.iteratorsize(T), Base.HasLength)
        Iterable()
    else
        NotIterable()
    end
```

which seems to work:

```
julia> iterability(Set)
Iterable()

julia> iterability(Number)
Iterable()

julia> iterability(Symbol)
NotIterable()
```

Comment: Thank you. That is definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether `a type` implements `an interface` via `methodswith` as follows:

```
foo(a_type::Type, an_interface::Symbol) = an_interface ∈ [i.name for i in methodswith(a_type, true)]

julia> foo(EachLine, :done)
true
```

<strike>but I don't quite understand the dynamic dispatch approach you mentioned in the comment, what does the generic function looks like? what's the input & output of the function? I guess you want something like this?</strike>

```
function foo(a_type::Type, an_interface::Symbol)
    # assume bar baz are predefined
    if an_interface ∈ [i.name for i in methodswith(a_type, true)]
        # call function bar
    else 
        # call function baz
    end
end
```

<strike>or some metaprogramming stuff to generate those functions respectively at compile time?</strike>

Comment: I understand your solution but this julia code is more verbose than the corresponding java code :) isn't there a cleaner way to check that in Julia?

Comment: @IssamT. so the question can be simplified as `merely knowing a type/"class" \`T\`, how to find its "methods"?`. since julia features multiple-dispatch, classes do not have their own methods, so this process is a little bit harder than other oop languages such as python and java.